# How to programmatically set WCF client maxBufferSize parameters?

Tags: wcf-binding

I am setting wcf client parameters programmatically like below:

```
try
{
ServiceReference1.MyDbServiceClient webService =
    new ServiceReference1.MyDbServiceClient(new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding(),
    new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress((string)((App)Application.Current).Resources["wcfMyDBServiceEndPoint"]));

    webService.GetSeriesImagesCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.GetSeriesImagesCompletedEventArgs>(webService_GetSeriesImagesCompleted);
    webService.GetSeriesImagesAsync(index);
}
```

It works just fine for the default maxBufferSize.  However when a client exceeds the default size, an exception is throughn: "the maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded."

How to set this parameter in code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 05, 00);
binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 05, 00);
binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 05, 00);
binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 05, 00);
binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;             

binding.GetType().GetProperty("ReaderQuotas").SetValue(binding, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max, null);
```

Create binding based on your requirement.

Comment: Thank you, you are right.  As well, my problem was that we have to have MaxBufferSize equal to MaxReceivedMessageSize too.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/d2090703-eb60-46f4-adf7-31127338a0a0/ Hope this will help

Comment: WCF is trying too hard to insulate us.  This is a good answer :)